# Indexing columns in MS Access and SAS export

Tags: excel, ms-access, indexing, sas

I have several scheduled jobs in SAS, which exports tables to Access. As the datasets are pretty large I want to index some of the columns to make searching more responsive when collecting the data from Excel. I tried to manually Index the columns using Design View (and this works), but when I export the tables from SAS again the index disappears. I've also tried the auto indexing feature in Access but it does not seem to work. Any idea on how I can solve this indexing problem ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You do need to improve your comments.

As for the solution, it can be done like this:

1. Export data in MS Access from SAS as you do
2. Run a VBA code from SAS that triggers the indexing.

You can find examples of triggering VBA code in [this SAS paper](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings16/7120-2016.pdf). 
You need to take into account the following: 
* Is your SAS running on Windows platform? Does it have the necessary drivers? 
* Can you SAS server access the MS Access database direct? 
* Do you have x commands enabled in your SAS environment?

Also, is it necessary to get the data in MS Access? Your organisation might have MS Excell Addon for SAS available (most likely) which means you can easily get data into Excel from SAS.

Example VBA:

```
Sub CreateIndexX1() 

    Dim dbs As Database 

    ' Modify this line to include the path to Northwind 
    ' on your computer. 
    Set dbs = OpenDatabase("Northwind.mdb") 

    ' Create the NewIndex index on the Employees table. 
    dbs.Execute "CREATE INDEX NewIndex ON Employees " _ 
        & "(HomePhone, Extension);" 

    dbs.Close 

End Sub
```